# Hadoop WordCount Tutorial java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: hadoop

I'm relatively new to hadoop and I'm struggling a little bit to understand the ClassNotFoundException I get when trying to run the job. I'm using the standard tutorial found [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html) and here is my WordCount class (running on ubuntu 16.04  hadoop 2.7.3 distributed cluster mode):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class WordCount {

  public static class TokenizerMapper
       extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
      while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
        word.set(itr.nextToken());
        context.write(word, one);
      }
    }
  }

  public static class IntSumReducer
       extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                       Context context
                       ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      int sum = 0;
      for (IntWritable val : values) {
        sum += val.get();
      }
      result.set(sum);
      context.write(key, result);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
    job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
  }
}
```

To try and remain organized, I added a couple paths to my ~/.bashrc file:

```
hduser@mynode:~$ cd $HADOOP_CODE
hduser@mynode:/usr/local/hadoop/code$
```

This is one directory down from the $HADOOP_HOME directory. To compile the WordCount.JAVA file, I ran:

```
hduser@mynode:/usr/local/hadoop$ hadoop com.sun.tools.javac.Main $HADOOP_CODE/WordCount.java
hduser@mynode:/usr/local/hadoop$ jar cf wc.jar $HADOOP_CODE/WordCount*.class
```

I then tried:

```
hduser@mynode:/usr/local/hadoop$ hadoop jar $HADOOP_CODE/wc.jar $HADOOP_CODE/WordCount /home/hduser/input /home/hduser/output/wordcount
```

which bombed with the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /usr/local/hadoop/code/WordCount
```

**EDIT**
This gave me the same error:

```
hduser@mynode:/usr/local/hadoop/code$ hadoop jar $HADOOP_CODE/wc.jar WordCount /home/hduser/input /home/hduser/output/wordcount
```

To get it to run without error, I moved the WordCount.Java file up one directory to the default hadoop ($HADOOP_HOME) folder. I also know from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700910/hadoop-java-error-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-w) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38584143/class-not-found-exception-in-hadoop) that the solution is to add a package to the file.

What I'm trying to understand is **why** that is the solution. With no package name, where is hadoop looking for the specified package, and why can't I pass it a full path to get it to run correctly? This may be a basic java question (apologies - I'm from the python world), but what is the package name doing during the compile process that makes it so I could run without a path name, but leaving off the package name means it has to be in that default directory? I'd prefer not to have to add a package name to every job I run. An explanation would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your argument `$HADOOP_CODE/WordCount` needs to be a class name, not a file path

Comment: And package names have periods, not slashes for  file paths, just like python modules

Comment: I tried just WordCount, but without the class being compiled into the $HADOOP_HOME folder it errored out. I wasn't trying to point to a package, I was trying to put a path to the class.

Comment: And what was the error then?

Comment: edited above - same error

Comment: And if you do `package com.example.mapreduce;` in the code and run with  `$HADOOP_CODE/wc.jar com.example.mapreduce.WordCount`, what happens?

Comment: Also does not work same error:  hadoop jar $HADOOP_CODE/wc.jar com.example.mapreduce.WordCount /home/hduser/input /home/hduser/output/wordcount2
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.mapreduce.WordCount

Comment: How are you building your JAR file?

Comment: Checking out the official tutorial, I know it used to have a package name, but it definitely doesn't use any `$HADOOP_CODE` variable. So, try it without variables first. http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#Example:_WordCount_v1.0

Comment: I know it doesn't - my basic question is how can I modify the tutorial to run from a different directory? I'd like to run from $HADOOP_CODE, which is 1 directory down from $HADOOP_HOME (/usr/local/hadoop). I can get the program to run in the $HADOOP_HOME directory just fine, but I don't want to always run jobs from there or that directory will get messy.

Comment: The only argument that needs the `$HADOOP_HOME` file path is the jar file. If you are getting a class not found, then something is incorrect about how your JAR is built; that is the second argument. The remaining arguments are HDFS filepaths, so `$HADOOP_HOME` should never get "messy" by running that command